# xceed wpf datagrid bound to hierachical dataset does not refresh tables

Tags: wpf, datagrid, xceed

I have an Xceed wpf datagrid that is bound to a dataset with related datatables. I am binding to a datatable property on the viewmodel using a DataGridCollectionViewSource in the ui. The datagrid binds to this static datagridcollectionviewsource. On loading up, the data is displayed in the grid as a hierarchy as expected. I am then defining a custom template for the default datacell which uses a ValueConverter where I perform some unit conversions. When the grid first loads, the converter gets called and the values are displayed as expected. However, when the user changes the conversion parameter, I would like the grid to be refreshed so the ValueConverter is invoked again in order to display the correct value.

However, I have just spent the last couple of hours going through the xceed documentation and they simply call Refresh method on the collectionviewsource. Doing this doesn't seem to be forcing the datagrid to invoke the ValueConverter for the datacell so I don't believe there is any Refresh happening.

Any help in resolving this would be appreciated.